# pythonの組み込み関数compileの利点って何ですか？どんな時に使われるかがいまいちわかりません。

Tags: python, python3, python2

pythonを仕事で使っていますが、まだpythonの深いところまであまり追求できていません。
あるpythonライブラリのソースを読んでいた時に、compileという組み込み関数を見つけ、以下の資料を元にどういった動作がするのかはわかりましたが、この組み関数compileはどういった用途で使われるのかがわかりませんでした。

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1704/28/news041_3.html
https://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html#compile

よくexec(compile())といったような使い方がされるそうですが、compileがなくても動作するはずです。

pythonの組み込み関数は一体どういう用途で使われるのでしょうか？お詳しい方がいましたが、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

`compile()`自体はほとんど使うことがない関数だと思いますが、例えば、Pythonコードを文字列やファイルで入力してそれを実行するPythonプログラム、といったメタプログラミング的用途が挙げられるそうです。その場合も`exec()`などでできますが、何度も実行する場合はコンパイルコードで持っていたほうが効率的です。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443939/python-built-in-function-compile-what-is-it-used-for